# Optimizing a code (which checks for the mod ==0 for a large no 10^18)

Tags: c, algorithm, optimization

I have a very big no say 'x' (10^18) and a number 'z' say 6.
I am trying to know/calculate using a c code that how many numbers in the range 1 to x(10^18) are divisible by z.
for that i am using a simple loop

```
While(x)
{
    if(x % z == 0)
       {
          count++;
        }
     --x;
  }
```

But this code is taking too much time as expected as it is checking all the values from 1 to x.
Is there any know algorithm or technique where i can optimize the above code and still get the same results.
Many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
count = floor(x / z);
```

Obviously, you will need a datatype big enough to hold `x`.

Comment: Aww beat me to it. But yes the solution is very simple.